# Show which class/traits/object are incorrect in IntelliJ's Project window

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

How do I have IntelliJ's Project window show me which class/traits/object are incorrect in terms of compiling - before compiling? This was shown in NetBeans back in the day.

I am talking about this window:

[image]

After all, IntelliJ is able to show me the little green tick in the upper right corner:

[image]

Comment: Try to compile project using your build tool

Comment: @AntonDozortsev: Thanks, but that is not what I mean. I am talking about before compiling. Please see edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work for Scala as for Java. You can see that file `Issue1.java` won't compile.

[image]

But you can use `Make Project` feature that will *Compile all modified and dependent files in a project* by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.